# yum error "Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again" updating ContextBroker

Tags: rpm, yum, fiware, epel

I'm trying to update Orion ContextBroker using the command yum install contextBroker. Unfortunatelly I get the following error:

> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security Loading
>
> mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>
> Error: Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel. Please verify
>   its path and try again

What could be going wrong ?

Comment: Suggested troubleshooting step: can your system `curl -v https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org`?

Comment: The selected answer is a workaround that doesn't fix the root issue, and in fact package installation may continue to fail.  I suggest deselecting the best answer, and let the vote count sort the answers to the one that worked for most people.

Comment: checking if date and time of your machine is correct, at least this was the case for me.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

I solved this issue editing both `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` and `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel-testing.repo` files, commenting all entries starting with `mirrorlist=...` and uncommenting all the entries starting with `baseurl=...`.

Comment: In my case, this fix allowed yum to successfully download metadata for the epel repo, but trying to install packages then failed with `[Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid`. The correct fix was to update ca-certificates, as in the answer below.

Comment: commenting all entries starting with metalink=... and uncommenting all the entries starting with baseurl=.... worked for me on RHEL7.1

Comment: Tried your method, then `yum clean all && yum update` worked. But not completely, it said  `epel-release-7-11.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try` etc. So I tried `yum update curl --disablerepo=epel` as sbetharia suggested, and tried `yum clean all && yum update` again, it finally worked now.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I had no `mirrorlist=` lines, but I had `metalink=` lines, and those needed to be commented.

Comment: This is the accepted answer, but as some of the answer may imply: there appear to be multiple possible causes of this. Maybe a community wiki would be good for listing them all?

Answer (score 200):

You just needed to update ca-certificates package. Before that just disable all repos with https that are failing.
That's why solution with commenting mirrorlist or using http instead https would work also.

For example if you need to disable only epel repo:

```
yum --disablerepo=epel -y update  ca-certificates
```

This will also help wget, curl, and anything else that uses SSL certificates.

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer, as it diagnoses the real source of the problem, rather than just providing a work-around.

Comment: I've tested this on the CentOS 6.5 [bento box](https://github.com/chef/bento) and it does make things slightly more reliable when running `yum clean all && yum makecache`.  However, it still fails sometimes.   Adding a retry to my script made it even more reliable.   I suspect that some mirrors are unreliable and a retry can give another mirror that works.  So if at first it doesn't succeed, try try again!

Comment: Wonder how you found that solution ... the error message was quite criptic for me

Comment: Well this comes from experience, and yes, message is cryptic :)

Comment: I needed this and also http://stackoverflow.com/a/31066100/41223 to sort my issue out.

Comment: make sure if you're behind a corporate proxy to also set it for https e.g. `export https_proxy=<your proxy>`

Comment: epel-repo RPM should have ca-certificates has dependency !!

Comment: thank you @Markus !!! - I had followed all the answers (except the ones saying to disable https) and it still wasn't working, actually the problem was I only set `http_proxy` and not `https_proxy`, how stupid of me :)

Comment: I also needed to update `curl` (or one of its dependencies) - I was getting `SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP` when trying to `curl https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org`.

Comment: I had a system I'd done a few updates on then fail as above on `centosplus` and `epel` - I found the solution was to disable both and just run `yum update`, then run it again with both repos enabled. As someone above hints... it's probably safest to do an update before you add epel's repo to a system ;-)

Answer (score 73):

use this command:

```
sudo sed -i "s/mirrorlist=https/mirrorlist=http/" /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
```

or alternatively use command

```
vi /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
```

go to line number 4 and change the url from

```
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
```

to

```
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
```

Comment: Thanks; this just worked for me after trying many of the other documented solutions (my error was, `Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel/x86_64. Please verify its path and try again`).  My question is, **why did this work?**  is this due to a configuration problem at the repository site?

Comment: Probably not the HTTPS server, but HTTPS client-side support on systems can go out of date, as root certificate authorities aren't updated, or the SSL libraries don't support new ciphers.

Comment: After many tries, solved with your sed command. Just Copy+Paste, that's what I needed because usually I'm not in charge of this kind of things, just installing a test computer to be used only by me to test some database updates.

Comment: In Cent OS 7.6, this is `sudo sed -i "s/metalink=https/metalink=http/" /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`

Answer (score 23):

Updating curl worked for us. Somehow yum uses curl for its transactions.

```
yum update curl --disablerepo=epel
```

Comment: Your answer is better than the accepted answer, needn't change epel.repo or epel-testing.repo.

Comment: I tracked this down and updated curl before reading this or some of the other answers.  I see that updating curl also updated nss... so I wonder if that was the issue.  In my case, I curl'ed the metalink URL, saw that it failed, and saw that it worked with --tlsv1 (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=1170339).  Assumed curl was out of date and updated it.  So now I wonder if NSS could have been updated w/o updating curl and it would have worked or not.

Answer (score 22):

I guess this should work. I solved my problem with this.

> $ sudo yum clean all
>
> $ sudo yum --disablerepo="epel" update nss

Comment: This woks for Centos 6.8. Thanks

Comment: This solved my issue also, I'm curious why the `update nss` helps solving this issue ?!

Comment: update nss didn't work for me but update curl after this did

Comment: This woks for Centos 6.5 too. Thanks

Answer (score 21):

For my case commenting out `mirrorlist` and uncomenting entries with `baseurl` din't work. I noticed the problem was with the `https` iniside the `.repo`fedora files. I solved it by going in `/etc/yum.repository.d` and replacing all `https` with `http` in different .repo files. That worked!!

Comment: This probably has to do with a proxy set in /etc/yum.conf (company proxy)?

Answer (score 11):

Check if you access internet through a proxy, and then your add internet proxy address to `yum` configuration.

add

```
proxy=http://ip:port
```

to `/etc/yum.conf`

Comment: make sure to have the https proxy also specified.

Comment: this worked for me, but only with additionally following parameter:
`proxy_username=your_user
proxy_password=your_passwd`

Comment: This works when in a corporate network or VPN. Thanks Rashad!

Answer (score 9):

Walkthrough Steps

Running the following command will update the repo to use HTTP rather than HTTPS:

```
sudo sed -i "s/mirrorlist=https/mirrorlist=http/" /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
```

You should then be able to update with this command:

```
yum -y update
```

Comment: The only solution which works for me! All the others have not changed anything to it (I need epel packages).

Comment: In Cent OS 7.6, this is `sudo sed -i "s/metalink=https/metalink=http/" /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`

Answer (score 7):

You may come across this message/error, after installing epel-release. The quick fix is to update your SSL certificates:

```
yum -y upgrade ca-certificates
```

Chances are the above error may also occur while certificate update, if so, just disable the `epel` repo i.e. use the following command:

```
yum -y upgrade ca-certificates --disablerepo=epel
```

Once the certificates will be updated, you'll be able to use yum normally, even the epel repo will work fine. In case you're getting this same error for a different repo, just put it's name against the `--disablerepo=<repo-name>` flag.

---

**Note**: use `sudo` if you're not the `root` user.

Comment: That's the best answer for me :)

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by this solution.

you just change in this file  /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo

mirrorlist= change this url  https to http

baseurl=  change this url  https to http

Answer (score 4):

All of the above did not work for me, but a rebuild of the rpm database, with the following command, did:

```
sudo rpm --rebuilddb
```

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Had to use baseurl instead of mirrorlist (accepted answer) before doing this

Answer (score 4):

For boxes that does not have internet access, you can remove `epel` repository:

`yum remove epel-release --disablerepo=epel`

This happened to me as I accidentally installed `epel-release` using `rpm` on a prod box.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue even though the ca-certificates package is up-to-date. The mirror https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/ is currently signed by `DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA` which is included in my `ca-bundle`

```
$ grep -A 3 "DigiCert High" /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt 
# DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDxTCCAq2gAwIBAgIQAqxcJmoLQJuPC3nyrkYldzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBs
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3
```

The reason why https connections failed in my case, was that system date was set to the year 2002 in which the `DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA` is not (yet) valid.

```
$ date
Di 1. Jan 11:10:35 CET 2002
```

Changing the system time fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. You Sir are a legend

Answer (score 4):

I tried most of these solutions and none of them worked for me.

The only thing that worked for me was to disable and remove the offending repo.

```
sudo yum --disablerepo=epel\* remove epel-release.noarch
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by going in /etc/yum.repository.d/. For my case i comment out mirrorlist and uncomenting entries with baseurl. as well as added sslverify=false.

https://serverfault.com/questions/637549/epel-repo-for-centos-6-causing-error

Comment: Not only that, but also changing the URLs to http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/source/SRPMS/
(for fedora.repo and fedora-updates.repo). Note the "archives" in front and the "pub/archive" in the path)

Comment: yum install -y yum-utils --disablerepo=epel && yum-config-manager --save --setopt=epel.sslverify=false

Answer (score 2):

I've workaround this issue by changing the https entries in epel.repo file to http.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when running a Centos 7 virtualbox VM on Windows 10. After much faff I found the error was coming from yum trying to use IPV6 so I had to edit /etc/yum.conf by adding:

```
ip_resolve = 4
```

I hope this helps someone else spend less time on this error than me!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check your "yum" configuration in /etc/yum.conf
Then do try above tips :-)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30201097)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the mirrorlist URL from https to http fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed mine like this:

```
yum install elfutils-default-yama-scope-0.168-8.el7.noarch --disablerepo=epel
yum install nss-pem -disablerepo=epel
yum reinstall ca-certificates --disablerepo=epel
yum clean all
rm -rf /var/cache/yum
yum update`
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me (I didn't even try the hacks like manually editing the repo file).

However it worked after a simple `yum update -y`

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause is that your architecture is not supported. I ran into this because I was provided with a CentOS VM, wanted to install EPEL and couldn't for the life of me get it done.

Turns out the VM was CentOS 7 i386, which is an architecture that is apparently no longer supported by EPEL. I guess the only remedy in this case is to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I comment out mirrorlist the error got away but the repo was also not working so I manually point the right baseurl in  `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` as below

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
baseurl=http://iad.mirror.rackspace.com/epel/7Server/x86_64/
#metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-7&arch=$basearch&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch - Debug
baseurl=http://iad.mirror.rackspace.com/epel/7Server/x86_64/debug/
#metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-debug-7&arch=$basearch&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
gpgcheck=1

[epel-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch - Source
baseurl=http://iad.mirror.rackspace.com/epel/7Server/SRPMS/
#metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-source-7&arch=$basearch&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
gpgcheck=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
yum clean all --enablerepo=*
```

Then

```
yum update --disablerepo=epel
```

Answer (score 0):

For obsolete CentOS 6, I used this in /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo

baseurl=https://d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net/pub/archive/epel/6/$basearch

Answer (score 0):

It works for me on centos 7:

```
yum update
yum install epel-release
sed -i "s/metalink/#metalink/" /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo 
sed -i "s/#baseurl=http:\/\/download/baseurl=https:\/\/archives/" /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
```