# yum installation manager not working in centos 6.6

Tags: centos, centos6, yum, centos6.5, epel

I'm facing a problem with yum installation manager in centos 6.6

```
root@mmopuru:~ # cat /etc/*release
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

root@mmopuru:~ # uname -a
Linux mmopuru.puppetlabs.vm 2.6.32-504.el6.i686 #1 SMP Wed Oct 15 03:02:07 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Its throwing following err. I tried clean all but no use.

```
root@mmopuru:~ # yum install python-pip
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Repository 'updates' is missing name in configuration, using id
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * ius: ftp.neowiz.com
 * remi-safe: mirror.innosol.asia
 * update: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/addons/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: addons. Please verify its path and try again
```

How to resolve this?

When I run yum repolist

```
root@mmopuru:~ # yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Repository 'updates' is missing name in configuration, using id
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                                                                    | 4.0 kB     00:00
 * epel: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * ius: mirror.amsiohosting.net
 * remi-safe: mirrors.thzhost.com
 * update: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/addons/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/addons/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
epel                                                                                                                                             | 4.3 kB     00:00
epel/primary_db                                                                                                                                  | 4.9 MB     00:05
ius                                                                                                                                              | 2.2 kB     00:00
ius/primary_db                                                                                                                                   | 194 kB     00:01
remi-safe                                                                                                                                        | 2.9 kB     00:00
remi-safe/primary_db                                                                                                                             |  22 kB     00:00
update                                                                                                                                           | 3.4 kB     00:00
update/primary_db                                                                                                                                | 3.7 MB     00:01
repo id                                                  repo name                                                                                                status
addons                                                   CentOS-6 - Addons                                                                                            0
*epel                                                    Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - i386                                                             9,857
ius                                                      IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - i386                                                       356
remi-safe                                                Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - i386                                                    32
update                                                   CentOS-6 - Updates                                                                                         989
repolist: 11,234
```

The content of /etc/yum.repos.d/centos-internal.repo is

```
root@mmopuru:~ # cat /etc/yum.repos.d/centos-internal.repo
# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# This file uses a new mirrorlist system developed by Lance Davis for CentOS.
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#

[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/PM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#released updates
enabled=0
[update]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/PM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#packages used/produced in the build but not released
[addons]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Addons
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=addons
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/addons/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/PM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/PM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
enabled=0
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/PM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#contrib - packages by Centos Users
[contrib]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Contrib
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=contrib
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/PM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

Comment: you got answer or not ? The answer given below by **Remi Collect** will solve the issue.

Comment: It solved by uncommenting **baseurl**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "addons" repository definition, which doesn't exists for CentOS 6 (it only exists for CentOS 5, but is empty).

Answer (score 1):

I have just answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734777/yum-error-cannot-retrieve-metalink-for-repository-epel-please-verify-its-path/40927019#40927019) i.e. same error but for EPEL repo. I am answering here, may be it can come helpful for some future SO user.

---

**Solution**: The quick fix is to update your SSL certificates:

```
yum -y upgrade ca-certificates
```

Chances are the above error may also occur while certificate update, if so, just disable the repo i.e. `addons` which is causing the error, use the following command:

```
yum -y upgrade ca-certificates --disablerepo=addons
```

In case you're getting this same error for a different repo, just put it's name against the `--disablerepo=<repo-name>` flag.

---

**Note**: use `sudo` if you're not the `root` user.